# Inno Setup how to set the AppId after user has selected destination directory?

Tags: inno-setup

In Inno Setup, I need to set the AppId after the user has selected the destination directory of the install. How can this be done? The documentation leads me to believe this can be done from this quote here, "If you use a {code:..} constant to allow your user to customize AppId, you do not need to return the real value until just before the installation starts:..."

What I am trying to accomplish is to set the AppId based on the user selected destination directory so that multiple copies of the application can be installed and displayed in the Add/Remove programs.

When I use something like

```
AppId={code:GetAppId}
```

the constant {app} has not yet been set in my "GetAppId" function.

Comment: I edited my post to clearly show what I am asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the [`AppId`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setup_appid.htm) directive value can be evaluated at early initialization of the setup, you cannot safely expand in its assigned scripted function [`{app}`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_consts.htm#app) constant nor even call the [`WizardDirValue`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_wizarddirvalue.htm) function because the [`{app}`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_consts.htm#app) constant requires to pass the directory selection page and the [`WizardDirValue`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_wizarddirvalue.htm) function requires a wizard form instance.

The only way then is to declare a flag variable which will indicate that the wizard form has been created for calling the [`WizardDirValue`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_wizarddirvalue.htm) function, or that the directory selection page has been passed if you decide to expand [`{app}`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_consts.htm#app) constant in your scripted constant function.

A script which uses the [`WizardDirValue`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_wizarddirvalue.htm) function for getting the selected directory may look like:

```
[Setup]
AppId={code:GetAppId}
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program
UsePreviousLanguage=no
OutputDir=userdocs:Inno Setup Examples Output

[Code]
var
  CanGetDir: Boolean;

function InitializeSetup: Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
  CanGetDir := False;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  CanGetDir := True;
end;

function GetAppId(Value: string): string;
begin
  Result := '';
  if CanGetDir then
    Result := ExtractFileName(WizardDirValue) + '123';
end;
```

A script which expands the [`{app}`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_consts.htm#app) constant to get the selected directory may look like:

```
[Setup]
AppId={code:GetAppId}
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program
UsePreviousLanguage=no
OutputDir=userdocs:Inno Setup Examples Output

[Code]
var
  CanGetDir: Boolean;

function InitializeSetup: Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
  CanGetDir := False;
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = wpSelectDir then
    CanGetDir := True;
end;

function GetAppId(Value: string): string;
begin
  Result := '';
  if CanGetDir then
    Result := ExtractFileName(ExpandConstant('{app}')) + '123';
end;
```

Comment: My research came up with that answer as well.  However, I get this error when I run the install:

    _Internal error: An attempt was made to expand the "app" constant before it was initialized._

Comment: Let me guess, *"An attempt was made to expand the "app" constant before it was initialized."* ?

Comment: Made an update. Sorry for misleading. I was blindly hoping it's evaluted just once before the installation starts without even trying. Shame on me :-)

Comment: I really appreciate the help!  Unfortunately, I cannot use `WizardDirValue` either because I get this error: _An attempt was made to access WizardForm before it has been created._

Comment: [`I'm giving up this`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/master/Projects/ScriptFunc_R.pas#L1655). There's a getter for `WizardForm`, which fails because of that early evaluation. Strange is that for me it was evaluated later, when the wizard form was already created. Well, my last comment to your problem. You must use some flag variable which will (ideally) indicate that you've passed the directory selection page and that you can expand `{app}` constant or call the `WizardDirValue` function for safe. Sorry, so trivial problem and it fails (for me worked this though). Good question!

Comment: That's what I was thinking too.  Now that you have shown me WizardDirValue I may be able to set a flag and get it to work.

Comment: Sadly, that's the only really safe way. I'll update the answer as you've accepted it. Thanks!